# How to prepare a 2x2 Confusion matrix for binary classifier, without code

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, confusion-matrix

Problem statement: Evaluate a binary classifier. There are 50 positive outcomes in the test data, and 100 observations. Using a 50% threshold, the classifier predicts 40 positive outcomes, of which 10 are incorrect. Calculate classifier’s Precision and Recall on the test sample?

My tried solution: I have calculated Precision as : P = TP / TP + FP => P = 40 / 40 + 10 => P = 0.8 And, same Recall. But, I am not sure its correct as F1 score options are not matching with mine.

So, I need to build a correct 2x2 Confusion matrix.

Please let me know for any query or information required to solve this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of *true positives* (TP) is 30 because you predicted 40 positives, however only 30 of them were correct. That would make your precision $$p=\frac{30}{40}=0.75$$

Similarly, for recall, it's $30/50$.